# How to copy a byte[] into a char*?

Tags: c++, c

All I need this for is strcpy().

I want to see whether the first three bytes of a buffer(byte array) are "JMX" as string.

This is what I did so far:

```
char * ddj;
strcpy( ddj, buffer ); //buffer is BYTE[]
if ( strcmp( "JMX", ddj ) == 0 ) //check first three chars are "JMX"
{
    buffer += 20;   //increase the index with 20
    size -= 20;     //int
}
```

I get exception at strcmp() line. What is the problem?

*I wish I was writing this in C# :(*

Comment: If you posted a question stating what you were actually trying to do, we could give you the optimal and easy  C++ way of doing it. You are currentyly using the sub-optimal, and frankly wrong, C way of doing it.

Comment: Once again when it comes to explicit memory management, most answers are techically incorrect. A strong indication that one should use std::vector or std:;string, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tho things go wrong here:

1. `ddj` does not point to any actual memory. Hence the copy will have undefined behavior
2. The copying is not necessary in the first place.

This is what you can do:

```
if(strncmp("JMX", buffer, 3) == 0) {
  buffer += 20;
  size -= 20;
}
```

This uses [strncmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) instead of [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), thus ensuring that no more than three bytes are compared. If `buffer` can contain less than three bytes, you should do something like:

```
if(buf_len >= 3 && strncmp("JMX", buffer, 3) == 0) {
  buffer += 20;
  size -= 20;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not allocating any memory for `ddj`.  Since it's a local variable, it's allocated on the stack.  Local variables are not initialized to 0/false/NULL by default, so the value of `ddj` immediately after it's declared is undefined -- it will have the value of whatever is left in memory at that particular location on the stack.  Any attempt to dereference it (that is, to read or write the memory at which it's pointing) will have undefined behavior.  In your case, it's crashing because it's pointing to an invalid address.

To fix the problem, you need to allocate storage for `ddj`.  You can either allocate static storage on the stack, or dynamic storage on the heap.  To allocate static storage, do:

```
// Allocate 64 bytes for ddj.  It will automatically be deallocated when the function
// returns.  Be careful of buffer overflows!
char ddj[64];
```

To allocate dynamic storage:

```
// Allocate 64 bytes for ddj.  It will NOT be automatically deallocated -- you must
// explicitly deallocate it yourself at some point in the future when you're done
// with it.  Be careful of buffer overflows!
char *ddj = new char[64];
...
delete [] ddj;  // Deallocate it
```

Instead of managing storage yourself, it would be a better idea to use `std::string`, which automatically deals with memory management.

Finally, since all you're doing is comparing the first three characters of the string, there's no need to jump through hoop to copy the string and compare it.  Just use [`strncmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp):

```
if(strncmp(buffer, "JMX", 3) == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated memory for ddj. Allocate memory using new to it . For example

```
char *ddj = new char[size]; //Allocate size number of chars
//do the required comaprisons

delete[] ddj; //Remember to release the memory.
```

On the other hand you can use std::string which is a standard string class.

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate new memory for `ddj`. Either declare it as

```
char ddj[NAX_LENGTH];
```

or with dynamic allocation

```
char* ddj = new char[length]; // You must use delete[] to free the memory in the end.
```

A more convenient alternative is `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's crashing because `ddj` doesn't point to anything.

Secondly, you don't need to copy the data from byte[] to char* (they're essentially the same thing). You can just do:

```
if (strncmp("JMX", reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), 3) == 0)
{
  // Strings are equal, do what you want
}
```

Comment: For builtin types, "static_cast" will only work on pointers where the implicit conversion will work anyway.  You should probably change this to "reinterpret_cast".

Answer (score 0):

This is UB because `ddj` isn't pointing to anything.  You need to allocate memory:

```
char* ddj = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
```

Be sure to `delete` the memory you allocated using `delete[]` (not plain `delete`!).

You could also use `std::string` which is generally safe, as you don't have to deal with pointers and memory alloation.

Looking at your code, however, `ddj` seems useless.  Just use `buffer`:

```
if ( strcmp( "JMX", buffer ) == 0 ) //check first three chars are "JMX"
{
    buffer += 20;   //increase the index with 20
    size -= 20;     //int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to strcmp ddj, you can also do it on buffer first, and make a copy of buffer if you need it later.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because the variable 'ddj' isn't initialized. It is pointing at garbage, so who knows where you are copying that string...

You don't really need to copy the bytes before comparing them, though.

```
if(strncmp("JMX", buffer, 3) == 0) // check if the first three characters are "JMX"
{
    buffer += 20;
    size -= 20;
}
```